# Согласование сказуемого при наличии дополнений

Tags: синтаксис, согласование

Помогите пожалуйста узнать, как правильно следует написать предложение:

Используйте библиотеку готовых слайдов, иконок и инфографики, **соответствующих** вашему контенту. - больше подходит по смыслу, так как используются слайды, иконки и тп.

или же

Используйте библиотеку готовых слайдов, иконок и инфографики, **соответствующую** вашему контенту. - смысл в том что подлежащее - библиотека, и согласование идет с ним.

Что в этом случае верно? Если можно с обоснованием, спасибо

Comment: Почему неприменно «библиотеку»? Есть другие слова: фонд, собрание, коллекция, подборка...

Comment: Жонибек, обратите внимание, что "библиотеку" здесь не подлежащее, а дополнение в винительном падеже; "соответствующую" не сказуемое, а определение. Из главных членов в этом предложении есть только сказуемое, выраженное глаголом в повелительном наклонении – "используйте".